# Vue app not working once building for production

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue.js application that I am trying to mock build for production so that I can test registering of a service worker to get it so I can send notifications (useful for the app not a spam one like some sites). The issue I am having is that when I build for production I try to login in a fresh incognito browser and I can log in but when my auth provider (Auth0) redirects back to my backend it fails on the callback saying it doesn't exist. However, if I use the same .env file when running `npm run serve` I can log in and have the callback URL work.

Process I am using

- Run `npm run buildProd` runs the commands `vue-cli-service build --mode production`
- Run http-server dist/
- Go to / which redirects to /login
- Log in via Auth0
- Redirect to /callback
- Error with 404 on redirect

Error message from http-server

```
"GET /callback?code=dcdc1EAzh2Vx0_cN&state=bkFzRWtoUnd5WGJfcGw1d0tuNU1Md0lILmFWTEhxcmZKY0IuQ0NrRE9lVA%3D%3D" Error (404): "Not found"
```

I am looking to see if anyone knows why this might be happening? I have not tried a full production deploy to the production infrastructure yet as I don't want to break it.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was not running Vue and serving the file in a supported format. I ended up creating a simple HTTP server using Node.js and serving the index.html file and it got rid of the error but introduced a new one I plan to ask about soon

Comment: What file was being served? Was the HTML in the `dist` folder after `build`?

Comment: You could use the NPM package `serve`

Comment: @nonNumericalFloat Um? 1 this is an old post and 2 that makes no sense at all. Vue is something that can be built into static assets and deployed to something like S3 compared to your idea of building a Node.js server/container and paying for compute to run `serve` which would be way more expensive. The serve package is used for local development and should NEVER be used for production. Heck even a Nginx server with static assets is better than your insane idea.